# Verbatim string is missing carriage return

Tags: c#, line-endings, verbatim-string

I have encountered a strange issue today.  I have a verbatim string like this:

```
var s = @"     0     1
0     0"
```

i.e. there is a new line after the one.  My Environment.NewLine is set to \r\n

This is part of a unit test and the tests have been working fine for the past several months.  Now when I run my tests the above string declaration is resulting in:

```
"     0     1\n     0     0"
```

instead of

```
"     0     1\r\n     0     0"
```

Meaning the tests fail.

I have dumped out every character to prove this is true.  I have also tried not using a verbatim string instead like this:

```
var s = "     0     1\r\n    0     0"
```

and the tests then pass.

Does anyone have any idea what could be happening here?

Comment: Maybe your source file literally has only `\n` - have you tried deleting the break and inserting it again, or else taken a look at the file with something that can show the actual bytes there?

Comment: Thats it!  I tried copying and pasting the code into notepad++ but obviously when I did that it corrected the line endings.  If I open the file directly the line endings for some reason have been changed to just LF#

Comment: Depending on a specific line ending is dangerous. Source control software (e.g. Git) might convert line endings on push or pull depending on the user's settings.

Comment: @cremor yes I've just learnt an important lesson there.

Comment: i think it must have been git that did it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the string in a unit test it is best to ensure the content is always the same. I suggest to declare it like this:

```
var s = $"     0     1{Enviroment.NewLine}0     0";
```

Comment: Can Environment.NewLine not change?  I appreciate its unlikely.  Better to actually use \r\n explicitly

Comment: The `Enviroment.NewLine` can be different depending on the OS the software is running. It depends on how the unit test is implemented if it will break or not. If you use `Enviroment.NewLine` on both places it will not break the unit test.

Comment: its a good point, I should be writing the data out using environment.newline.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is this:  Git (most probably) swapped the line endings in the file to just LF.  Depending on file line endings in unit tests is not a good idea so I have changed the code to specify the newlines explicitly in all cases, thus:

```
var s = "     0     1\r\n    0     0"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string interpolation together with verbatim to add control characters.

```
var s = @$"     0     1{'\r'}
0     0"
```

Comment: i did not know that, thanks. however would the above not result in "      0     1\r\r\n0     0" ?

Comment: Depends which editor you use to enter the the new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71674571/2066007) - basically it is caused by code editor end of line settings. We faced the same issue in unit tests.