# C# - multiline verbatim string does not contains carriage return (\r) for new lines in Visual Studion 2022

Tags: c#, string, verbatim-string

We are facing issue when defining verbatim multiline strings (`@"some string"`) in Visual Studio 2022. Although we are compling code on Windows machine and variable `Environment.NewLine` defines `\r\n` as new line, verbatim multiline string contains just `\n`. See below.

[image: MissingCariageReturn]

Does anybody have idea why carriage return is missing in string?

Comment: What does your source file have as the line endings for that part of the code? I suggest you examine it in a binary file editor. `Environment.NewLine` is irrelevant.

Comment: Soo... That's XML - why are you worried about whitespace?

Comment: In Windows `\r` is optional. When you go to next line, by default the cursor will point to the beginning of the line.

Comment: The thing is that we have written unit tests, which compares generated XML against the predefined value. Unfortunately it passes on some workstations (which are generating `\r\n` and it fails on some workstations (as on mine where the line break is defined just only as `\n`

Comment: Bear in mind that there's likely a difference between newlines in .Net and whatever environment it's running under Windows/MacOS/Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found answer, thanks to [John Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) who gave me a hint.

Behaviour was caused by the code editor - in our case Visual Studio 2022. Basically each code editor allows you to define line breaks behaviour and you can override it by settings in `.editorconfig` - property `end_of_line` - see [documentation](https://editorconfig.org/#supported-properties)

Here is an example of the `.editorConfig` file:

```
# To learn more about .editorconfig see https://aka.ms/editorconfigdocs
[*.cs]
end_of_line = crlf
```

You can also define behaviour for files in Git repository using `.gitattributes` file:

```
*.cs text eol=crlf
```

Visual Studio also allows you to reformat current file using option `Edit->Advanced->Set End of Line Sequence` but this is just applied to currently opened file.
[image]